# How to Increase Pose Movement Speed in ARCore

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I am working on an application in Unity ARCore SDK for visualizing a room with marker detection on android mobile phones. There is no problem in creating the room model when marker is detected. The problem is, when user moves in the room, its movement is very slow in the unity world. For instance when user moves 5 meters in real world, its position on the model just changes 1 meter. How can i increase the change in position?

I can't scale down the size of the model. Because when i do that, the model not aligns with the real world, it becomes much much smaller.

Comment: That cant be related to ARCore probably you have fps issues or something else. Is your room model too detailed?

Comment: No it is not. I do not have fps issues either. This problem happens because model is too big. When i scale it down the user's real world movement will correspond with its unity world movement but i do not want to do this.

Comment: I am working on a similar project i align a model of the room and i have no problem with the tracking of the device. Do you have a video of the problem you can share? Also, ARCore or Unity position unit is meters did you consider this in your model?